# A sql script to startup and shutdown all Oracle services

Tags: sql, oracle

How to write a script which will startup and shutdown all Oracle services?
I need to save it as service.sql and run it from sqlplus as @service.sql

I can do it from sqlplus just typing :

```
shutdown normal;
startup
```

but when I put these 2 commands to a sql file and run it as SYSTEM. I get these error:

```
SQL>@service.sql
ORA-01031: insufficient priveleges
ORA-01031: insufficient priveleges
```

I know I can do it using batch file but i have to do it using only sql and the OS is windows 7.

Comment: You don't show how you are connecting, which is critical.  My guess is you are not connecting with sysdba privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SYSDBA` and `SYSOPER` system privileges allow you to perform STARTUP and SHUTDOWN operation in Oracle Database.

```
SQL>conn system/password 
SQL>shut immediate
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
SQL>conn system/password as sysdba
SQL>@service.sql
```